# Batch combine images with Opacity map at a time with Imagemagick

Tags: image, batch-file, imagemagick, transparency, alpha

I have a directory full of image in the form *_Alb.png and *_Opa.png, with the Opa files being a black and white "opacity map" for the Alb image. I want to convert the opacity map to the alpha channel of the Albedo image, and there's about 100 of both in this folder, and I want to send it to another folder at output.*/png

I'm able to do it for single images, using the following:

```
magick [filename]_Alb.png [filename]_Opa.png -compose CopyOpacity -composite done/[filename].png
```

but any attempt I've done to try to automate this for multiple images doesn't work. Here's my current attempt using a batch file:

```
@echo off 
setlocal enableextensions enabledelayedexpansion
set file=before 
for /R [folder path] %%a in (./*Alb.png) do (
    set "file=%%a"
       magick !file:~34,0! !file:~34,-8!_Opa.png -alpha Off -compose CopyOpacity -composite output/!file:~34,-8!.png
)
```

to which it gives the following output for every line:

```
magick: image sequence is required `-composite' @ error/operation.c/CLIListOperatorImages/4057.
```

Comment: You will not be able to use `mogrify` when each input file requires a different alpha file - its syntax doesn't permit that. So, if you are stuck with Windows, you'll need to use the clunky old batch file method or Powershell or Python. If you have tried some batch file method, please click [edit] and add that to your question. You should be able to use a `FOR F IN *_Alb.png` to iterate over your albedo files and then calculate the name for each one's alpha buddy and the corresponding output file.

Comment: yeah that's what i tried. I've edited the post to add the attempted batch file I did. I have very little experience with batch files so this is all i was able to do with a few hours of trial and error and googling.

Comment: `!file:~34,0!` means "starting at the 34th character, take 0 characters." It will always return an empty string. If you wanted to start at the 34th character and grab the rest of the string, that's just `!file:~34!`

Answer (score 1):

I've managed to figure it out myself

```
@echo off 
setlocal enableextensions enabledelayedexpansion
set file=before 
for /R [file path] %%a in (./*Alb.png) do (
    set "file=%%a"
    magick !file:~34,-8!_Alb.png ^
  ( +clone -alpha extract !file:~34,-8!_Opa.png -compose Multiply -composite ^) ^
  -compose CopyOpacity -composite ^
  output/!file:~34,-8!.png
)
```

The error I was getting was fixed by changing `!file:~34,0!` to `!file:~34,-8!_Alb.png` despite the two of these should have had the same output. I'm unsure how this worked, and if anyone would like to elaborate as to why it would be appreciated, my theory is there was some character magick didnt know how to handle at the end.

The original albedo files had their own transparency, so to combine them instead of discarding it I was able to find the `+clone` line online. It's not needed if the original albedo file doesn't have any transparency, and can just be done how I did it in the first post.

Comment: Cool, well done! And thank you for sharing back with the StackOverflow community.

Answer (score 1):

There seems no reason, based upon your question details, to use a recursive command. I might therefore offer this alternative idea.

```bash
@Echo Off
SetLocal EnableExtensions DisableDelayedExpansion

Set "SourceDir=S:\ource Dir"
Set "MagickExe=P:\ath To\magick.exe"

PushD "%SourceDir%" 2>NUL || GoTo :EOF
If Not Exist "%MagickExe%" GoTo :EOF

For /F "Delims=" %%G In ('"(Set PATHEXT=) & %SystemRoot%\System32\where.exe .:"*_Alb.png" 2>NUL"') Do (
    Set "BaseName=%%~nG"
    SetLocal EnableDelayedExpansion
    If Exist "!BaseName:~,-3!Opa%%~xG" (If Not Exist "done\." MD "done"
        "%MagickExe%" "%%G" "!BaseName:~,-3!Opa%%~xG" -compose CopyOpacity -composite "done\!BaseName:~,-4!%%~xG"
    )
    EndLocal
)

PopD

Endlocal
GoTo :EOF
```